# How to filter or extract specific CSS ruleset from a .css file and put it in a separate file

Tags: css, node.js, webpack, fs, webpack-plugin

Is it possible to extract or filter some specific CSS ruleset from a .css file using webpack (using plugin perhaps) or nodejs, and put it in a separate file (fs node)? If yes how?

e.g.

I want to extract `.my_class1` ruleset from `all.css` and put it in separate file `extracted.css`

**Before Extraction**

```css
/* all.css */

.my_class1 {
  color: red;
  background: red;
}


.my_class2 {
  color: green;
  background: green;
}

.my_class3 {
  color: blue;
  background: blue;
}
```

**After Extraction**

```css
/* all.css */

.my_class2 {
  color: green;
  background: green;
}

.my_class3 {
  color: blue;
  background: blue;
}
```

```css
/* extracted.css */

.my_class1 {
  color: red;
  background: red;
}
```